# Access files on linux from nodejs with case insensitivity

Tags: node.js, linux, filesystems, fs

I am accessing files from nodejs dynamically, but I am facing a problem when user creates a directory with different case like (/hello) and try to access it with different case like (/Hello). Is there a way that I can access directories on linux through nodejs with case insensitivity?

Comment: So if a user creates two files, `file1.txt` and `File1.txt`, which file should he get via `GET /FILe1.txt`?

Comment: Let us assume that he will never create files with same names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a case-insensitive filesystem your best bet is probably going to be just reading the list of files in the requested file's directory and do a case-insensitive comparison. For example:

```
var requestedPath = '...';
fs.readdir(path.dirname(requestedPath), (err, names) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  var requestedFile = path.basename(requestedPath).toLowerCase();

  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    if (names[i].toLowerCase() === requestedFilename)
      // do something
  }
});
```